# Optional filter parameter in a functionto either filter or not filter data

Tags: r

I am triying to come up with a function that takes a filter as the parameter. For instance, using `mtcars` dataset as an example. Suppose I just want to filter the dataset by selecting only `mpg` is bigger than 21. Below is my code

```
mtcars_func<-function(df,mpg_filter=NULL){
  filter<-df%>%transmute(filter_a=mpg>mpg_filter)
  df%>%filter(!!!unname(filter))
}
outcome<-mtcars_func(mtcars,21)
```

By doing so, I do get what I want, which is rows that only match my condition `mpg` >=21. However, what if I want to have the option not to feed in any filter and just have this function spits out non-filtered data? How would I modify this function to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can have `missing` to check the `mpg_filter`

```
mtcars_func<-function(df,mpg_filter=NULL){

  if(missing(mpg_filter)) {
     df
     } else {
    df%>%
       filter(mpg > mpg_filter)
   }
   }
mtcars_func(mtcars,21)
mtcars_func(mtcars)
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use a default of `-Inf`

```
mtcars_func<-function(df, mpg_filter = -Inf) {
  filter(df, mpg > mpg_filter)
}

mtcars_func(mtcars,21)
mtcars_func(mtcars)
```

Comment: This is smart! But seems only apply to numeric columns, am I correct?

Comment: The function is already hard coded to mpg_filter so there is no loss in generality.  If mpg were replaced with a character column you could use "" as the default.